# К ста двадцатилетию или к сто двадцатилетию?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: К ста двадцатилетию или к сто двадцатилетию?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно К СТОДВАДЦАТИЛЕТИЮ. СТОДВАДЦАТИЛЕТИЕ - это существительное.

Из общего правила склонения сложных слов с первым корнем-числительным есть 4 числительных-исключения: "один", "девяносто", "сто" и "тысяча". После них гласная в сложных словах остаётся соединительной гласной, а не окончанием (и поэтому не изменяется при склонении), как после всех остальных числительных. 
Источник: Розенталь"Справочник по правописанию и литер. правке" (М., 1978), стр. 37, пункт 6. 
Готовый ответ нашла  [здесь](http://otvet.mail.ru/question/62669948).